# Getting TypeError: numeral_1.default is not a function in value converter

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I've installed `numeral.js` via npm and added in `aurelia.json` in the vendors bundle, I then use it from a value converter:

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

export class CurrencyValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return numeral(value).format('$0,0.00')
  }

}
```

I get the following error `TypeError: numeral_1.default is not a function`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `import * as numeral from 'numeral'`

Comment: I was just navigating to this to comment I found the answer :)